# asp.net membership login with alternate password

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I am making an ASP.NET application and using ASP.NET membership controls for users to login. I want user can login using his normal password or a quick login (which allows user to create a 4 digit password similar to ATM PIN) for a quick login experience.  How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extend the basic membership provider and use it. Here is a start point.

```
public class DoublePasswordProvider : SqlMembershipProvider
{
    public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        if (checkPIN(username, password)) return true;
        return base.ValidateUser(username, password);
    }
}
```

Then edit we.config to use it:

```
<membership defaultProvider="DoublePasswordProvider">
      <providers>

        <add name="DoublePasswordProvider" type="YourNamespace.DoublePasswordProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

Finally use standard asp.net controls (login, change password, bla bla)

Comment: should I add another field in aspnet_Memberhip table?

Comment: This could be a solution. Avoid storing pins in "plain text" on the database (for security reason). Always use encryption or (even better) hashing.

Comment: but then how would I define membership control to check for alternate password i.e. how will login control be linked with the SqlMembershipProvider control that you have provided

Comment: If you use the default asp.net login control it will use the web.config configuration to determine the membership provider to use. If you need a custom control use "bool valid = Membership.Provider.ValidateUser(username, password);". It will use web.config too

Answer (score 0):

For a start, you could have a look at [ASP.NET Login Controls Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and the variations described.

Basic Tutorials can be found at:

- [Using Basic Forms Authentication in ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/authentication)
- [How to handle security and authorization in your Web Forms applications using ASP.NET membership and roles.](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security)
- [Login control in asp.net](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=login%20control%20in%20asp.net&oq=login%20con&gs_l=youtube.3.0.0l3j0i5l4.1680.2955.0.4011.9.9.0.0.0.0.79.591.9.9.0...0.0...1ac.1.VkYymlVqAys)

Hope that helps.